# Rails combining lines in a query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I run the following working query in rails:

```
@slos = Answer.joins(knowledge_topic: :student_learning_outcomes).select( 
        'student_learning_outcomes.title', :is_correct, "count(answers.id) AS 
        total_answers").group('student_learning_outcomes.id', :is_correct)
```

Which gives me a table like:

```
ID     correct? No.
Q1     true     234
Q1     false    122
Q2     true     251
Q2     false    144
Q3     true     227
Q3     false    198
```

I would like to combine the 2 rows for each question:

```
ID     Correct  Incorrect
Q1     234        122
Q2     251        144
Q3     227        198
```

I have no idea how to attempt this, so I would appreciate some suggestions, even if it is just pointing me to a good source as I had no luck googling it.

Thank you.

**Table Structure Edit**

**Tables**

Answers

```
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :answers do |t|
      t.references :question, index: true
      t.references :section, index: true
      t.references :student, index: true
      t.references :knowledge_topic, index: true
      t.boolean :is_correct
      t.string :answer_text
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Knowledge Topics

```
class CreateKnowledgeTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :knowledge_topics do |t|
      t.string :knowledge_area
      t.string :knowledge_unit
      t.string :knowledge_topic
      t.integer :year_added
      t.boolean :active
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Student Learning Outcomes

```
class CreateStudentLearningOutcomes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :student_learning_outcomes do |t|
      t.string :accredidation_body
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.integer :year_added
      t.boolean :active
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Knowledge Topics Covering SLO's

```
class CreateSloCoveredByKts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :slo_covered_by_kts do |t|
      t.references :student_learning_outcome, index: true
      t.references :knowledge_topic, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Models**

Answers

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :knowledge_topic
end
```

knowledge topic

```
class KnowledgeTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :slo_covered_by_kts 
  has_many :student_learning_outcomes, through: :slo_covered_by_kts
end
```

Student learning outcome

```
class StudentLearningOutcome < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :peo_covered_by_slos
  has_many :program_educational_objectives, through: :peo_covered_by_slos
  has_many :slo_covered_by_kts 
  has_many :knowledge_topics, through: :slo_covered_by_kts
end
```

Slos covered by Knowledge topics

```
class SloCoveredByKt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student_learning_outcome
  belongs_to :knowledge_topic
end
```

Comment: can you provide the structure of the tables in question?

Comment: I meant the database tables... :p

Comment: Yeah that's sufficient. I was looking more for the actual table description (such as if you do `desc [table_name]` in MySQL) but that's good enough. Where is the `Q1` and `Q2` values coming from; is that the value of `student_learning_outcomes.title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach to this problem is to use `count(expression)`, which returns the

> number of input rows for which the value of *expression* is not null

So to count correct answers, we need to create an expression that returns non-null when the answer is correct and null when the answer is incorrect (and vice versa to count incorrect answers). We can use `case` to accomplish this, and the result looks like this:

```
@slos = Answer.
  joins(knowledge_topic: :student_learning_outcomes).
  select( 
      "student_learning_outcomes.title",
      "count(*) as total_answers",
      "count(case when is_correct = 't' then 1 else null) as correct_answers",
      "count(case when is_correct = 'f' then 1 else null) as incorrect_answers").
  group("student_learning_outcomes.id")
```

Note that we drop `:is_correct` from both the `select` and `group` expressions, and the number of correct and incorrect answers appear as `.correct_answers` and `.incorrect_answers` methods on each returned object in `@slos`.

Also note that I changed your `count(answers.id)` to `count(*)`. For all practical purposes they mean the same thing -- `count(answers.id)` is counting the number of rows in each group that have a non-null id (which should be all of them), and `count(*)` is simply counting the number of rows in each group.

Comment: Todd, this certainly looks simpler and cleaner. I'd like to add one minor point: the OP is eventually generating a table that resembles an object of `StudentLearningOutcome`. Thus 'starting' from `Answer` is counterintuitive. It would be more suitable to 'start' from the most relevant model and apply joins to it i.e. `StudentLearningOutcome.joins(knowledge_topics: :answers)`

Comment: I hadn't really looked at the provided models, but now that I have, I agree with you: an Answer represents a single response to a question from a student, so summarizing on that model doesn't make a lot of sense; coming from the opposite direction is definitely the way to go, and it seems the OP knows that as they're using `@slos` to store the results of the query.